# Why is this nested resource link_to looking for "destroy" instead of "show"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just trying to get the link to point to "user/1/post/1".  I've tried using the link_to with and without the :method key and got the same results.

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Posts#index

Showing /home/test/rails_apps/test_app/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #22 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts", :user_id=>#<Post id: 1, content: "wtf", user_id: 1, created_at: "2010-10-27 20:46:46", updated_at: "2010-10-27 20:46:46">}

Extracted source (around line #22):

22:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_post_path(p), :method => :get %></td>
```

Comment: Can you post some more context around line 22?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the ":method" argument.  It specifies an HTTP method, not the action.

Comment: Ok.  I changed it to :get from :show and it's still looking for the destroy route.

Comment: I'd expect it to still be a problem, I just wanted to make sure that that was one issue that *wasn't* causing it.  I also upvoted because I don't completely understand why this is happening either.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `user_post_path(p)` where I guess `p => Post Object`

But this route will also need a user object, hence this resource will evaluate to `a post of a user`

Have a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)

It says

```
In addition to using the routing helpers, Rails can also create paths and URLs from an array of parameters. For example, suppose you have this set of routes:

resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end

When using magazine_ad_path, you can pass in instances of Magazine and Ad instead of the numeric IDs.
<%= link_to "Ad details", magazine_ad_path(@magazine, @ad) %>

You can also use url_for with a set of objects, and Rails will automatically determine which route you want:
<%= link_to "Ad details", url_for([@magazine, @ad]) %>
```

Hope this helps.